# How to delete mysql-client

Tags: mysql, uninstall

I want to delete mysql-client. I installed mysql-client and mysql-server by command:

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`

And now I can't remove it.

```
cyberha4@cyberha4-VirtualBox:/var/www/html$ sudo apt-get remove mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
```

"Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed", but it installed and i use it. Similar things happend when i tried to delete 'mysql-server' and some other packages. Whats wrong?

I used command:

```
cyberha4@cyberha4-VirtualBox:/var/www/html$ apt list --installed| grep mysql*
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
libdbd-mysql-perl/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.033-1ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libmysqlclient20/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
mysql-common/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
php7.1-mysql/xenial,now 7.1.8-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 i386 [installed]
```

And I didn't see mysql-client or server.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-5-completely/16178696#16178696) helped me, after delete mysql and reinstalled it, all packages started showing up after command

> cyberha4@cyberha4-VirtualBox:/var/www/html$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql*
>   mysql-client                    install
>   mysql-client-5.7                install
>   mysql-client-core-5.7               install
>   mysql-common                    install
>   mysql-server                    install
>   mysql-server-5.7                install
>   mysql-server-core-5.7               install
>   php7.0-mysql                    deinstall
>   php7.1-mysql                    install

Comment: during the installation, have you confirmed it installed properly. cos it says package not found. I suggest you use purge. `sudo apt-get purge mysql*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

I hope you get some help. :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks so much, its delete mysql, but after i installed mysql again (im learning ubuntu) and saw that command 'sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client' installed 9 packages and they are displayed correctly when i use command dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql*

Comment: some of the those packages are just dependencies and you should not worry much about it.